# Django Rest Framework + Datatables + Class Based Views + Server Side Processing

Tags: django, datatable, datatables, django-rest-framework

How to use Django Rest Framework  + Datatables + Class Based Views?

Comment: what do u want to hear from us?

Comment: Hey my friend, i answered my own question. This is a solution that worked for me and may help others. Keep your postmodernist correctness for yourself. @Chiefir

Answer (score 0):

This is a python snipped to use Django Rest Framework  + Datatables + Class Based Views.

```
import re

from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response


class DataTablePagination(LimitOffsetPagination):  # pragma: no cover

    """Custom pagination class for datatable server side processing."""

    limit_query_param = "length"
    offset_query_param = "start"

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        """See datatables server side processing."""
        return Response({
            "recordsTotal": self.count,
            "recordsFiltered": self.count,
            "data": data,
            "draw": int(self.request.GET["draw"])
        })

    @staticmethod
    def get_datatable_ordering(request):
        """Parse datatables conf parameters."""
        ordering = []
        columns = dict()

        for key in request.GET:
            if key.startswith('columns'):
                col = dict()
                keys = [i[1:-1] for i in re.findall(r'\[\w+\]', key)]

                for i in range(len(keys) - 1):
                    if i == 0:
                        if keys[i] not in columns: columns[keys[i]] = dict()
                        col = columns[keys[i]]
                    else:
                        if keys[i] not in col: col[keys[i]] = dict()
                        col = col[keys[i]]

                col[keys[-1]] = request.GET[key]

        if 'order[0][column]' in request.GET:
            ret = columns[request.GET['order[0][column]']]['data']
            if request.GET['order[0][dir]'] != 'asc': ret = '-' + ret
            ordering.append(ret.replace('.', '__'))

        return ordering


class DatatablesView(GenericAPIView):  # pragma: no cover

    """Base view with datatables server side integration."""

    ordering = ("id",)

    def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Enable server side processing for datatables and `q` searching."""
        request.GET = request.GET.copy()

        if 'draw' in request.GET:
            self.pagination_class = DataTablePagination
            self.ordering = self.pagination_class.get_datatable_ordering(
                request) or self.ordering

            if 'length' in request.GET and str(request.GET['length']) == '-1':
                request.GET['length'] = 1e9

            if 'search[value]' in request.GET:
                request.GET['search'] = request.GET['search[value]']

        elif 'q' in request.GET and 'search' not in request.GET:
            request.GET['search'] = request.GET['q']

        return super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How did you resolve the image upload using editor @jsmedmar? I am using the drf-datatables-editor and still haven't figured out upload.